# Google apps Script Resource tool

Tags: google-apps-script

how to create a drop down in google apps script so that for next drop down it show me only specific entries regarding the first one .Like I select India as Country in first drop down and then in second only indian state list being populated.

Comment: What kind of interface are you building? Could you post some code?

Comment: hi i m creating a resource tool ..for a hotel room booking ...like i select building from one drop down  dn second drop down will automatically populate rooms acc to that building

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you thinking of something [like this](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx85RZuiw75MNA8v2eco50PGtpM7vSmXaGDT1XjXCmj39FP0501/exec) ?

The code is very simple, just add items to list 2 in a handler function triggered by list1

Data are defined in a 2D array. Here is the full code of this small demo app.

```
      var subItems = [['subCategory 1 of 1','subCategory 2 of 1','subCategory 3 of 1','subCategory 4 of 1'],['subCategory 1 of 2','subCategory 2 of 2','subCategory 3 of 2','subCategory 4 of 2'],
                      ['subCategory 1 of 3','subCategory 2 of 3','subCategory 3 of 3']];

function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('test listBox');
  var panel = app.createHorizontalPanel().setStyleAttribute('padding','40px');
  var sHdlr = app.createServerHandler('updatelist').addCallbackElement(panel);
  var items = ['category 1','category 2','category 3'];
  var list1 = app.createListBox().setName('list1').setId('list1').addChangeHandler(sHdlr);
  var list2 = app.createListBox().setName('list2').setId('list2').addItem(' .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .').setStyleAttribute('marginLeft','40px');
  for(var i =0;i<items.length;++i){list1.addItem(items[i],i)}
  panel.add(list1).add(list2);
  app.add(panel);
  return app;
}    
    function updatelist(e){
      var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
      var orig = e.parameter.source;
      if(orig=='list1'){
        var listVal = Number(e.parameter[orig]);
        var list2 = app.getElementById('list2').clear();
          for(var i =0;i<subItems[listVal].length;++i){
            list2.addItem(subItems[listVal][i],i);
            }
          }else{
        //do something else
        }
    return app;
    }
```